# Using Simplify to perform substitutions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

I have a matrix element $k_x$ and I want to substitute it as $-i\kappa$, I tried

```
Simplify[
  Subscript[H, s], 
  {B == 0, Subscript[k, x] == -I κ, Subscript[k, y] == κ}] // MatrixForm
```

However, the result shows $k_x$ in some elements in the matrix and $-i\kappa$ some place. How do I substitute all of them? I did a quick test but found the result just gives $k_x$.

```
Simplify[
  Subscript[k, x], 
  {B == 0, Subscript[k, x] == -I κ, Subscript[k, y] == κ}] // MatrixForm
```

I have played with `ReplaceAll` at the very beginning, but I actually want to do something in this way, is there any flexible way I can do a replacement?

```
Subscript[H, 01] = 
  FullSimplify[
    ArrayFlatten[({
      {Simplify[Subscript[H, S], {Subscript[k, x] == 0, Subscript[k, y] == 0}], 
       Simplify[
         Subscript[H, S], 
         {B == 0, Subscript[k, x] == -I κ, Subscript[k, y] == κ}]},
      {Simplify[
         ConjugateTranspose[Subscript[H, S]], 
         {B == 0, Subscript[k, x] == I κ, Subscript[k, y] == κ}],
       Simplify[
         Subscript[H, S], 
         {Subscript[k, x] == 0, Subscript[k, y] == 0}] + ℏ ω IdentityMatrix[4]}
      })], 
    {α, β, γ, κ, ζ, Subscript[k, x], Subscript[k, y]} ∈ Reals];
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Look up `ReplaceAll`.  Also read this answer, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395, and pay attention to what it says about subscripts and `MatrixForm`, in case that is an issue.  If you include an example for `Subscript[H, s]`, folks will better be able to say what the precise issue is.

Comment: Good, thanks. I find out ReplaceAll [Subscript[H, s],k_x->-i \[kappa]] work better than Simplify

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rule = Subscript[k, x] -> I*κ
```

Then any expression you may treat as follows: `expression/.rule`. For example:

```
expression = Subscript[k, x]^2 + Subscript[k, x]
expression /. rule
```

returns:

```
(*   Subscript[k, x] + \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(k\), \(x\), \(2\)]\)  *)

(*  I κ - κ^2 *)
```

Have fun!